# Thermal conductivity fitting using Callaway model

Tags: fitting

I want to fit the thermal conductivity of silicon at different temperatures using Callaway model, which can be expressed as:

[image]

where vB is the speed of sound, wD is the Debye frequency. They are known for silicon.

The fitting parameters are L, B(=B1+B2), and A.
The code I used is as follows.

[image]

```
Silicon = {{2, 0.44`}, {4, 3.11`}, {6, 8.99`}, {8, 16.4`}, {10, 
   24}, {20, 47.7`}, {30, 44.2`}, {40, 36.6`}, {50, 28}, {100, 
   9.13`}, {150, 4.1`}, {200, 2.66`}, {300, 1.56`}, {400, 
   1.05`}, {500, 0.8`}, {600, 0.64`}, {700, 0.52`}, {800, 
   0.43`}, {900, 0.36`}, {1000, 0.31`}, {1100, 0.28`}};

hbar = 1.054571817*10^-34;(*Plank constant*)
kB = 1.380649*10^-23;(*Boltzmann constant*)
\[Theta] = 645; (*Debye temperature*)
\[Omega]D = \[Theta] kB/hbar;(*Debye frequency*)
v = 2200;(*speed of sound in silicon*)

\[Kappa][T_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{\[Omega]}, 1/(2 Pi^2 v) \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Omega]D\)]\(
\*FractionBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\((hbar)\), \(2\)]*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \(4\)]*kB\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(T\), \(-2\)]\), \(v*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(L\), \(-1\)] + B\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(T\), \(3\)] 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \(2\)] + A\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \(4\)]\)]*
\*FractionBox[\(Exp[hbar*\[Omega]/kB*T]\), 
SuperscriptBox[\((Exp[hbar*\[Omega]/kB*T] - 
         1)\), \(2\)]] \[DifferentialD]\[Omega]\)\)]

FindFit[Silicon, \[Kappa][t, L, B, 
  A], {{L, 0.01}, {B, 3*10^-24}, {A, 1*10^-44}}, t]
```

This silicon example came from [enter link description here](https://nanohub.org/wiki/RoleofNormalProcessesinThermalConductivityofSilicon), and similar values of L, B, and A are expected.

The problem is that some error messages were generated, and the fitting seem endless. Could you please help to point out where is the issue. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several typos in the $\kappa$ definition compare to paper linked. For the best result we need to map integral domain on the unit interval by substitution $\omega\rightarrow \omega/\omega_D$, also we redefine parameters `A, B` as $\omega_D^4 A,\omega_D^2 B$, `L*F` as `L` and finally we have

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Silicon = {{2, 0.44`}, {4, 3.11`}, {6, 8.99`}, {8, 16.4`}, {10, 
       24}, {20, 47.7`}, {30, 44.2`}, {40, 36.6`}, {50, 28}, {100, 
       9.13`}, {150, 4.1`}, {200, 2.66`}, {300, 1.56`}, {400, 
       1.05`}, {500, 0.8`}, {600, 0.64`}, {700, 0.52`}, {800, 
       0.43`}, {900, 0.36`}, {1000, 0.31`}, {1100, 0.28`}};

hbar = 1.054571817*10^-34;(*Plank constant*)
kB = 1.380649*10^-23;(*Boltzmann constant*)
\[Theta] = 645; (*Debye temperature*)
\[Omega]D = \[Theta] kB/hbar;(*Debye frequency*)
v = 2200;(*speed of sound in silicon*)

\[Kappa][T_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ] := 
   (hbar)^2*(\[Omega]D)^5 /(2 Pi^2 v kB) Module[{\[Omega]}, 
    int = NIntegrate[ ( \[Omega]^4* T^-2)/(
       v*L^-1 + B T^3 \[Omega]^2 + A \[Omega]^4)*
       Exp[hbar*\[Omega]D  \[Omega]/(kB*T)]/(Exp[
          hbar*\[Omega]D \[Omega]/(kB*T)] - 1)^2, {\[Omega], 0, 1}, 
      PrecisionGoal -> 2, MinRecursion -> 5]; int];
```

Using data for silicon we can estimate parameters `A, B, L` starting from the point computed in the paper linked as follows

```
ff = FindFit[Silicon, \[Kappa][t, L, B, 
     A], {{L, 
    0.8}, {B, \[Omega]D ^2 2.9*10^-24}, {A, \[Omega]D ^4 0.22*10^-44}}, t]

(*Out[]= {L -> 6.92903*10^-6, B -> 7.59535*10^6, A -> 2.47228*10^13}*)
```

Visualization of fitted data and `ff`

```
Show[Plot[ \[Kappa][t, L, B, 
      A] /. ff, {t, 2, 1100}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[Silicon, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Note, that for parameters published in [the paper](https://nanohub.org/wiki/RoleofNormalProcessesinThermalConductivityofSilicon) and using as a starting point in our model we have very large discrepancies with data as shown in the picture below

```
Show[Plot[ \[Kappa][t, L, B, 
      A] /. {L -> .8 10^-6, B -> \[Omega]D ^2 2.9*10^-24, 
    A -> \[Omega]D ^4 .22*10^-44}, {t, 2, 1100}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[Silicon, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thanks! Your code works well on my laptop. But should we place kB on the numerator， not on the denominator. In this way, we have:   (hbar)^2*(\[Omega]D)^5 kB /(2 Pi^2 v). But when I made such a little change, I got a message saying "FindFit::fmgz: Encountered a gradient that is effectively zero. The result returned may not be a minimum; it may be a maximum or a saddle point." It is very strange.

Comment: Why do you need to put `kB` in numerator? This is one from several typos in your code. Please, pay attention on  expressions for $k, I_1, I_2$ in section 3. While $k=\frac {k_B}{2 \pi^2 c}(I_1+\beta I_2)$, $I_1,I_2$ are proportional $1/k_B^2$, and therefore $k$ is proportional to $1/k_B$.